# What makes it legitimate to multiply both sides?

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification

Having the proof of the cancelation law for multiplication:

$$cb=ab$$

$$(cb)b^{-1}=(ab)b^{-1}\tag{Inverse}$$

$$cbb^{-1}=abb^{-1}\tag{Associativity}$$

$$c\cdot 1=a\cdot 1\tag{Indentity}$$

$$c=a$$

This may seem stupid, but exactly at the second step: I can multiply both sides by the inverse, but is this a consequence of the [field axioms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_(mathematics)) or of the equality defined as an equivalence relation? I guess it's the second one, but I'm not sure if one could prove it with the field axioms alone.

Comment: Are you asking why $A=B$ implies $AC=BC$? It is because the multiplication is a well defined function.

Comment: These are properties of groups. Every group has an identity element, and every element in the group has an inverse.

Comment: You can apply a function to both sides of any equality. Even in settings where we aren't talking about numbers. Even when we're just talking about barren, structureless sets and elements of sets, we can apply a function to both sides of an equality. Of course, for any $u$ in an algebraic structure with a binary operation, there is a function $f(x):=x\cdot u$.

Comment: Write your proofs in complete grammatically correct sentences, specifying exactly what all the initial assumptions are,  and which direction(s) the implications go, and why each step is justified. Do not skimp on the words. Then you can see exactly what you have said and where,if any , the errors are .

Comment: Your "operation" is a "function".  And functions have this property (the "vertical line property"): if $x_1=x_2$, then $f(x_1)=f(x_2)$.

Comment: You are proving the implication $cb=ab\implies c=a$ but the converse implication $c=a\implies cb=ab$ is not yet available? I would have expected the latter implication to come first, since it seems more basic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One of my teachers I think seemed to dislike "multiplying" both sides of an equation by the same element. If you share the same aversion you can almost always use something like this to avoid it.

$$c = c \cdot e = c \cdot(b \cdot b^{-1}) = (c \cdot b) \cdot b^{-1} = (a \cdot b) \cdot b^{-1} = a \cdot(b \cdot b^{-1}) = a \cdot e = a$$

All we have used here is the associative law for the product and substitution which is a much more fundamental concept than the definition of a group.

---

But for the record I have no issues writing,

$$ c = a \implies cb = ab $$

since all we use here is the fact that $$c= a \implies (c, b) = (a, b) \implies f(c, b) = f(a, b)$$

where $f : G \times G \to G$ is the binary product on $G$ which is a well-defined function.

Answer (score 7):

Because if there were some operation you could perform on the two quantities to get different results, they would not be equal.

If two things are equal, the results of multiplying them each by $b^{-1}$, or of performing any other operation on them, must be equal, because that is what it means for two things to be equal.

Comment: Yes, I know. But my question concerns to the formalization of this idea. See Berci's and anon's comments.

Comment: I think this ultimately depends on the definition of "equal", which is an *axiom* in set theory. In hand-wavy words, if $a = b$ then $a$ and $b$ are *two names that denote the same thing*.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, you can prove it from the properties of real numbers.

Proof: 
If $a$, $b$, and $c$ are any real numbers, and $a = b$.

$ac$ is a unique real number $\iff$ closure property of multiplication

$ac = ac$  $\iff$reflexive property of equality

$a = b$ given

$ac = bc$ $\iff$ substitution principle